# Is use of [excel] OK for [google-spreadsheet] specific questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is it acceptable for posts that are specifically about [google-spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) such as [this question about TIMESTAMP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034494/how-to-make-dates-remain-static-after-first-edit-using-timestamps-on-google-shee) to include the [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) tag?

Would it be out of line to comment that the post has no relevance to the [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) tag? and ask for it to be removed?

Comment: For the record, originally the question was tagged with just [tag:excel], then someone added [tag:google-spreadsheet] with this comment: *"Added relevant tag (Left Excel tag, as solution may be portable and it will get more eyes)"*

Comment: The linked question was deleted :(

Answer (score 5):

Well, the real problem is that most [google-spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) and [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) questions, like the one you linked to, are not *programming* questions and should not be asked here, but on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com). The tag excerpt even says so:

> Questions related to interacting with Google Sheets spreadsheets programmatically. *Usage questions about the web application should be posted at Web Applications Stack Exchange.*

(emphasis mine).

But, other than that, [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) is not a synonym for 'spreadsheet', even though Microsoft likes to see it this way, so it makes no sense at all for that question (and a lot of others) to be tagged with [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel).

Comment: I agree that the question quoted shouldn't be on SO but it's just one that was asked recently with the dual tagging.  There are many others.

Comment: Yes, feel free to edit out the Excel tag in those cases (and remember to fix other issues with the question as well).

Comment: Actually, I very much doubt Microsoft likes to see it that way. At least according to US law, [genericization of a trademark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark) is a bad thing for a the company that holds the trademark. If "excel" were to become a widely-used generic name for "spreadsheet", Google could rename their "Google Sheets" product to "Google Excel".